# How can I make cygwin aware of enthought python?

Tags: python, cygwin, scipy, enthought

I need scipy on cygwin, so I figured the quickest way to make it work would have been installing enthought python. However, I then realized I have to make cygwin aware of enthought before I can use it, e.g. so that calling Python from the cygwin shell I get the enthought python (with scipy) rather than the cygwin one.

How do I do that?

I can guess my question is easy, but I'm just learning about all of this and so please be patient :-)

Comment: You *might* find it easier to install scipy (*and* python?) under Windows rather than under cygwin, then put the Windows version in Cygwin's path.  I don't currently use scipy myself, but I've read that a lot of people have trouble getting it to work right under Cygwin.

Comment: That's precisely what I want to do. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Think about uninstalling the cygwin version of Python, at least to start with. It's easy enough to reinstall later.

- Copy your Windows path.
- Install the Windows version of Enthought Python.
- Examine the new Windows path. The new entries *probably* have to be transferred to your bash shell in cygwin. (I haven't seen Enthought. There might be more than one new path entry.) But test without changing the bash path, just to be sure.
- Add the new path entries to, umm, .bashrc, I think. The path under cygwin will be a colon delimited string. You'll need to use the /cygdrive path; expect to use an entry like this to put Entought in the path.

  /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Enthought

To actually *do* that, edit .bashrc, and put these two lines (or something like them) at the end.

```
PATH=$PATH:/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Enthought
export PATH
```

Note that the backslash allows proper interpretation of spaces in file paths. The export statement guarantees that programs called by bash will also include that path.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the directory with enthought python before the directory with Cygwin's python in your path. If both are in the same directory, use ln to create a symbolic link, store it in another directory, and place it higher in your path. The previous answer has instructions to add it to your path.